# How to get external cdn to 'override' scss/css that is defined with component in angular8?

Tags: angular

In my angular8 app, I have a app.component.scss file where I define styles there.
I am also using bootstrap4, which I include an external CDN link to bootstrap.min.css at the end just before the close of the body tag.

When I inspect my angular8 app, I know a body style from bootstrap.min.css should override... but I don't see that in the app when I do an "ng serve". Is there some way that I can ensure that the bootstrap.min.css loads 'first' before the styles in my app.component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your CDN link in `head` tag of `index.html`.

This will ensure that `bootstrap` will load first.

Else, if you have installed the `bootstrap` dependency in your project, then import the `css` in `angular.json` styles tag.

```
{
 ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demong",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```